# Phoenix and nested content_tags with multiple children remove nested content

Tags: html, tags, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have such structure in my project:

```
content_tag(:div, class: "some-class", role: "alert") do
  content_tag(:button, type: :button, class: "close") do
    content_tag(:span, class: "some-other-class") do
      {:safe, ["&times;"]}
    end
  end
  content_tag(:button, type: :button, class: "close") do
    content_tag(:span, class: "some-other-class") do
      {:safe, ["&times;"]}
    end
  end
  "<span><b>Some bold text</b>and nothing more</span>"
end
```

And expect it to generate such HTML:

```
<div class="some-class" role="alert">
  <button class="close" type="button">
    &times;
  </button>
  <button class="close" type="button">
    &times;
  </button>
  <span><b>Some bold text</b>and nothing more</span>
</div>
```

However, it gives me something unexpected (I've added new lines for readability - in original everything is in one line):

```
<div class="some-class" role="alert">
  <button class="close" type="button">
    &lt;span&gt;&lt;b&gt;Some bold text&lt;/b&gt;and nothing more&lt;/span&gt;
  </button>
</div>
```

I do not really understand, how to join two nested `content_tag`s into one `:safe` string, at the same time making this string `"<span><b>Some bold text</b>and nothing more</span>"` safe and not be escaped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I've almost figured it out. This code should look almost like this:

```
content_tag(:div, class: "some-class", role: "alert") do
  [content_tag(:button, type: :button, class: "close") do
    content_tag(:span, class: "some-other-class") do
      {:safe, ["&times;"]}
    end
  end,
  content_tag(:button, type: :button, class: "close") do
    content_tag(:span, class: "some-other-class") do
      {:safe, ["&times;"]}
    end
  end,
  {:safe, ["<span><b>Some bold text</b>and nothing more</span>"]}]
end
```